# Increasing the number of threads makes the program slower

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, linked-list, pthreads

I'm currently trying to implement a linked list with multithreading access to it by using read-write locks. Though it does seem to work correctly I've been trying to see what was the performance improvement when i was increasing the number of threads and as it turns out performance actually gets worse:

- with a 100.000 operations and 1 thread elapsed time is 6.59 secs
- with a 100.000 operations and 2 threads elapsed time is 6.68 secs
- with a 100.000 operations and 4 threads elapsed time is 6.69 secs

The pattern is the same with different numbers of operations and threads. Though the slowdown is not really significant I surely expected to see some kind of improvements compared to the serial version. I've tried changing the order of the linked lists operations to avoid too much write lock contention but the problem still persists.
(additionally for some reason MacOS doesn't let me run the program with more than 200.000 operations)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

struct list_node_s {
    int data;
    struct list_node_s * next;
};

int Member(int value, struct list_node_s ** head);
int Insert(int value, struct list_node_s ** head);
int Delete(int value, struct list_node_s ** head);
void * threadOp(void * my_rank);

pthread_rwlock_t lock;
long n;
long thread_count;
struct list_node_s * head_p; 


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    double i = 0;
    clock_t begin = clock();
    n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    thread_count = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
    pthread_t * thread_handles = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * thread_count);
    long thread;
    

    printf("Will create %ld threads \n", thread_count);
    pthread_rwlock_init(&lock, NULL);
    
    struct list_node_s head = {.data = 0, .next = NULL};
    head_p = &head;
    
    for (i = 1.0; i < n; i++){
        Insert(i, &head_p);
    }

    for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, threadOp, (void *) thread);

    for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);

    pthread_rwlock_destroy(&lock);
    clock_t end = clock();

    double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    printf("Elapsed time %lf \n", time_spent);
}

int Member(int value, struct list_node_s ** head){
    struct list_node_s * curr_p = * head;
    
    // traverse list until end or we got to right value
    while(curr_p != NULL && curr_p -> data < value)
        curr_p = curr_p -> next;

    if (curr_p == NULL || curr_p -> data > value){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

int Insert(int value, struct list_node_s ** head){

    struct list_node_s * curr_p = * head;
    struct list_node_s * pred_p = NULL; 
    struct list_node_s * temp_p;
    
    while (curr_p != NULL && curr_p -> data < value){
        pred_p = curr_p;
        curr_p = curr_p -> next;
    }
    if (curr_p == NULL || curr_p -> data > value){
        temp_p = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node_s));
        temp_p -> data = value;
        temp_p -> next = curr_p;
        if (pred_p == NULL)
            *head = temp_p;
        else
            pred_p -> next = temp_p;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int Delete(int value, struct list_node_s ** head){
    struct list_node_s * curr_p = * head;
    struct list_node_s * pred_p = NULL;

    while (curr_p != NULL && curr_p -> data < value){
        pred_p = curr_p;
        curr_p = curr_p -> next;
    }
    // value was found and curr_p is not null
    if (curr_p != NULL && curr_p -> data == value){
        // first element in list
        if (pred_p == NULL){ 
            * head = curr_p -> next;
            free(curr_p);
        } else{
            pred_p -> next = curr_p -> next;
            free(curr_p);
        }
        return 1;
    } 
    // value not in list 
    else{ 
        return 0;
    }
}


void * threadOp(void * my_rank){
    long thread = (long) my_rank;
    long local_n = n / thread_count;
    long a = local_n * thread;
    long b = a + local_n;

    printf("Thread %ld is executing\n", thread);
    // half of threads will execute n members
    for (long i = a; i < b; i++){
        pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);
        Member(i % 15, &head_p);
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
        if (i % 10000 == 0){ 
            // other half will execute n/4 Ins and n/4 Del
            pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);
            Insert(i, &head_p);
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
        }
        else if (i % 10002 == 0)
        { 
            // other half will execute n/4 Ins and n/4 Del
            pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);
            Delete(i, &head_p);
            pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The way you measure the time is wrong. `clock` measure the CPU time and not the wall clock time. You should use `clock_gettime` or `gettimeofday`. This is certainly why you think the program is slower while it is probably not.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I've replaced clock with clock_gettime using CLOCK_REALTIME as the clock of reference but the problem still persists

Comment: Note that you should use `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead, but this should not change the timing outcome.

Comment: @JérômeRichard oh okay thanks for the tip

Comment: I just tested your code on my machine. **The benchmark is biased** : it measures the time of the `Insert` which takes >99% of the execution time. The time to run the threads and complete the work is only few milliseconds on my machine compared to ~6 seconds for the Insert`.

Comment: On top of that, the work is so small that the time to start, schedule and wait the thread can be significant compared to the actual work. Thus, it does not scale. A bigger work is needed for parallelism to be useful (or the creation/deletion of threads needs not to be included in the benchmark since threads can be reused in a real-world application). Moreover, the time of the insert/delete is not negligible compared to the work so the writers can be a bottleneck. Also please note that `malloc`/`free` tends not to scale in parallel.

Comment: Finally, note that writers might wait for the readers to complete and then do their operations. In this case, writers will be a lot slower because they then need to do the (differed) read. In such a case, some threads can end significantly later than others. The final parallel time can thus be higher with more threads due to the join. Such non-trivial contention issue is quite frequent with RW locks. It is good to delay writers for some applications while for some others it is better for writers not to be delayed. In general, people tends to give the priority to readers (slowing down writers).

Comment: Multiple threads accessing shared, modifiable data structures in a thread-safe way ordinarily **is** slower than accessing non-shared or non-modifiable data structures.  There is a cost for making accesses thread safe when modifications by other threads need to be accounted for.  The advantage is largely that those threads can do *other* work in parallel with each other, between accessing the shared data.  That can make the program faster overall, but whether in fact it does so depends deeply on the details.